# Check textField.text isEqualToString

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield

I have qtyTextFields that are added to a custom `UITableViewCell` dynamically.
What I am trying to do is detect if the user has inputted the string 0 in the `UITextField` and removing an object from an `NSMutableArray` if so. (I get how to remove the object from the `NSMutableArray` thats fine)

This implementation below does nothing for me and doesn't even log anything:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{  
    if ([qtyTextField.text isEqualToString: @"0"])
    {
        NSLog(@"You ENTERED 0");
        [theProducts removeObjectAtIndex:qtyTextField.tag];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"basket.plist"];
        [theProducts writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Do Nothing");
    } 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: The obvious question is whether you've remembered to set your object as the delegate of the text field.  If you have, then it's possible that the field doesn't know it's finished editing (i.e. is still first responder).  I find it easier to use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` for filtering since it doesn't depend on anything except what's entered.

Comment: Its ok I am being an idiot it should be if ([textField.text isEqualToString: @"0"]){ NOT if ([qtyTextField.text isEqualToString: @"0"]){

Comment: Hmmm...but you said you weren't getting any logging....

Comment: You said: **doesn't even log anything**. So we assume that the method is not even called... Unless there is a third route inside your `if`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the UITextField instance you get from the method? so the if statement would read:

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString: @"0"]){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: He says that nothing is outputted, so your answer does not fit.

Comment: Hi dragon yes I spotted my mistake just after posting and added a comment I should have used what the method provides i.e textField not qtyTextField! I will mark as correct when it lets me :-)

Comment: @AlexMcPherson Good to hear:)  @ JackyBoy the textField variable is different than his. so my answer does fit.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't even log anything, it sounds like you don't have the delegate set on your text field.  Do that first and then you should see "`DO NOTHING`" or "`You Entered Something`" appear in your log.

Answer (score 0):

There may be various condition due to which your code is not working :-

1.You might have not implemented the UITextFieldDelegate in .h file

2.You might have not set the textfield delegate in viewDidLoad method

```
myTextField.delegate=self;
```

You may use this code

```
if([myTextField.text length]==0)
{
//Show some error
}
else
{
if([myTextField.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@",@"0"]])
{
//Your Operation
}
}
```

Here you may have to keep in mind the setting of textfield delegate .If it is on a tableview then it's delegate will be tableviewcontroller , if u have one else the viewcontroller.

Comment: You dont need to check the length of the textfield as it will give an empty string (`@""`) which is not the same as `@"0"`